# undefined reference to functions (c++)

Tags: c++, function, reference, undefined

I searched this issue before asking and I found that everyone was using .h files for their functions, whereas my teacher has taught us to have main and the functions in one file.

I just want to figure out why it is undefined. I understand there could be other issues lurking in this code, but I really can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void start();
void process();
void check();
void deposit();

const float dserv = 0.10;
const float cserv = 0.15;
const float fiveserv = 5.0;
const float oserv = 10.0;

int main()
{
float balance;
float amount;
bool fivehun;
bool endcheck;
float servcharge;
float servchargetotal;
char type;

start();
while(endcheck != true)
{process();}
cout<<"Current balance: $"<<balance<<endl;
cout<<"Total service charges: $"<<servchargetotal<<endl;
cout<<"Final balance: $"<<
system("pause");
return 0;
}

void start(float balance)
{
    balance = 0;
    cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
    cout<<"Transactions will take the form of a letter followed by a dollar ";
    cout<<"amount. Valid letters are “C” for a check, “D” for a deposit, and";
    cout<<"“E” for the ending transaction (use zero on this transaction).";
    cout<<"Press <Enter> after each line of input";
    cout<<"Enter the beginning balance:"<<endl;
    cin>>balance;
}

void process(float balance, float amount, char type, bool endcheck)
{
    cout<<"Enter a transaction:"<<endl;
    cin>>type>>amount;
    if (type = "C"||"c")
    {check();
    endcheck = false;}
    else if(type = "D"||"d")
    {deposit();
    endcheck = false;}
    else if(type= "E"||"e")
    {endcheck = true;}
}

void check(float balance, float amount, bool fivehun, float servcharge, float& servchargetotal)
{
    balance = balance - amount;
    servcharge = cserv;
    if (balance<500.00)
    {fivehun = true;}
    else
    {fivehun = false;}

    cout<<"Transaction: Check in amount of $"<<amount<<endl;
    cout<<"Current balance: $"<<balance<<endl;
    cout<<"Service charge: Check - $"<<cserv<<endl;
    if (fivehun == true)
    {cout<<"Service charge: Below $500 - $"<<fiveserv<<endl;
     servcharge = (fiveserv+servcharge);}
    cout<<"Total service charges: $"<<servcharge<<endl;
    servchargetotal = servchargetotal + servcharge;
}

void deposit(float balance, float amount, bool fivehun, float servcharge, float& servchargetotal)
{
    balance = balance + amount;
    servcharge = dserv;
    if (balance<500.00)
    {fivehun = true;}
    else
    {fivehun = false;}

    cout<<"Transaction: Deposit in amount of $"<<amount<<endl;
    cout<<"Current balance: $"<<balance<<endl;
    cout<<"Service charge: Check - $"<<cserv<<endl;
    if (fivehun == true)
    {cout<<"Service charge: Below $500 - $"<<fiveserv<<endl;
     servcharge = (fiveserv+cserv);}
    cout<<"Total service charges: $"<<servcharge<<endl;
    servchargetotal = servchargetotal + servcharge;
}
```

If there is anywhere I can elaborate, I will try to edit/comment whatever I can.

Comment: You're writing too much code at once; start smaller, check your `start` function works before you move onto the `process` function and so on. There are many mistakes in the later functions and it may be overwhelming to try and debug your program with so much going wrong at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `start` function as said M.M. You should get something like this:

```
float start() {
    // ...
    float balance;
    cin >> balance;
    return balance;
}


int main() {
    float n;
    n = start();
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

And check all functions step by step because you have a problem in next `process` function: in if statement must be comparison operator `if (type == "C" || type == "c")` instead assignment `type = "C"||"c"`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The consistency of your answer with the others here were very helpful in narrowing down my particular issue.

Answer (score 3):

You declare a function `void start();` . And you call it with `start();` .

However you never provided the body for this function.  The function you defined as `void start(float balance)` is a *different function*. In C++ there may be several functions with the same name but different parameter lists; these are different functions.

You have a similar problem with `process()` and so on.

---

Your functions are supposed to be passing and returning the variables that they use, but you didn't actually write functions to do that.  The `balance` in `void start(float balance)` is a different variable to the `float balance` inside `main()` ; the changes you make inside this function will not affect `float balance;` in `main`.

To fix this particular function, it should be:

```
float start();
```

in both the prototype and the function definition; and you should have `float balance;` inside the function, and then end with `return balance;`. Then you call in `main` like so:  `balance = start();`

Your course materials should cover passing values to functions and returning values from functions, you will need to consult them to fix your other functions.

Comment: I reviewed course materials and I've got my program running perfectly, save for some formatting and cleaning up the output.  Thank you for your quick and extremely helpful response!

Answer (score 0):

You define the following functions:

```
void start();
void process();
void check();
void deposit();
```

You implement:

```
void start(float balance)
void process(float balance, float amount, char type, bool endcheck)
void check(float balance, float amount, bool fivehun, float servcharge, float& servchargetotal)
void deposit(float balance, float amount, bool fivehun, float servcharge, float& servchargetotal)
```

The definitions must match the implementations.

Alternately you can get rid of the definitions if you put the implementations ahead of  their first use (in `main`) in the file.

The function calls match the definitions, but when the compiler (the linker, actually) goes looking for a function implementation that looks like `void start()` it finds `void start(float balance)` and concludes these are not a close enough match.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code. This will help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void start(float balance);
void process(float balance, float amount, char type, bool endcheck);
void check(float balance, float amount, bool fivehun, float servcharge, float& servchargetotal);
void deposit(float balance, float amount, bool fivehun, float servcharge, float& servchargetotal);

const float dserv = 0.10;
const float cserv = 0.15;
const float fiveserv = 5.0;
const float oserv = 10.0;

int main()
{
float balance;
float amount;
bool fivehun;
bool endcheck;
float servcharge;
float servchargetotal;
char type;

start(balance);
while(endcheck != true)
{process(balance, amount, fivehun, servcharge, servchargetotal);}
cout<<"Current balance: $"<<balance<<endl;
cout<<"Total service charges: $"<<servchargetotal<<endl;
cout<<"Final balance: $"<<
system("pause");
return 0;
}

void start(float balance)
{
balance = 0;
cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
cout<<"Transactions will take the form of a letter followed by a dollar ";
cout<<"amount. Valid letters are “C” for a check, “D” for a deposit, and";
cout<<"“E” for the ending transaction (use zero on this transaction).";
cout<<"Press <Enter> after each line of input";
cout<<"Enter the beginning balance:"<<endl;
cin>>balance;
}

void process(float balance, float amount, char type, bool endcheck)
{
cout<<"Enter a transaction:"<<endl;
cin>>type>>amount;
if (type = "C"||"c")
{check(balance, amount, ...);
endcheck = false;}
else if(type = "D"||"d")
{deposit(balance, amount, ...);
endcheck = false;}
else if(type= "E"||"e")
{endcheck = true;}
}

void check(float balance, float amount, bool fivehun, float servcharge, float& servchargetotal)
{
balance = balance - amount;
servcharge = cserv;
if (balance<500.00)
{fivehun = true;}
else
{fivehun = false;}

cout<<"Transaction: Check in amount of $"<<amount<<endl;
cout<<"Current balance: $"<<balance<<endl;
cout<<"Service charge: Check - $"<<cserv<<endl;
if (fivehun == true)
{cout<<"Service charge: Below $500 - $"<<fiveserv<<endl;
 servcharge = (fiveserv+servcharge);}
cout<<"Total service charges: $"<<servcharge<<endl;
servchargetotal = servchargetotal + servcharge;
}

void deposit(float balance, float amount, bool fivehun, float servcharge, float& servchargetotal)
{
balance = balance + amount;
servcharge = dserv;
if (balance<500.00)
{fivehun = true;}
else
{fivehun = false;}

cout<<"Transaction: Deposit in amount of $"<<amount<<endl;
cout<<"Current balance: $"<<balance<<endl;
cout<<"Service charge: Check - $"<<cserv<<endl;
if (fivehun == true)
{cout<<"Service charge: Below $500 - $"<<fiveserv<<endl;
 servcharge = (fiveserv+cserv);}
cout<<"Total service charges: $"<<servcharge<<endl;
servchargetotal = servchargetotal + servcharge;
}
```

Comment: Needs indentation and an explanation of how this fixes OP's problem. Without an explanation this only teaches how to cut and paste, not how to avoid the problem in the future.

Comment: I noticed what you had actually changed, this also helped me get the program running 100%.  Thank you for taking the time to code out a response!